# normal to hyperplane $ 0.5x_1-5.5x_2-2.5x_3+9x_4 \le 0 $

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I want to find the equation of the the normal to the hyperplane   $$0.5x_1-5.5x_2-2.5x_3+9x_4 \le 0.$$   How can I find that ?

Comment: First of all, your inequality does **not** define a *hyperplane* (but rather a closed half-space). Do you mean something else?

Comment: I want to find eqn of  normal of half-space .

Comment: The line through the origin and $(a,b,c,d)$ will be normal to the hyperplane $ax+by+cz+dw=0$, won't it?

Comment: Post your comment as answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "normal" to a *half-space,* but the normal to its boundary (a hyperplane) is easy to read off from the equation.

Notice that $ax_1+bx_2+cx_3+dx_4=0$ can be written as $$(a,b,c,d)\bullet (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=0,$$ where "$\bullet$" is the usual dot product on the vector space $\mathbb{R}^4$. So the vectors in the hyperplane are precisely all those orthogonal to $(a,b,c,d)$. Thus the line from the origin to $(a,b,c,d)$ is the normal to the hyperplane.